# What is the appropriate smart pointer to use when passing an object to a function which will create it

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

If I have a setup as below, what would be an appropriate smart pointer type to use? Or is this a case where a raw pointer should be used instead?

```
void factory (some_ptr_type_here<A> a)
{
    a = some_type_of_new<A>(...,..);
}
some_ptr_type_here<A> a;
factory(a);
```

Comment: You'd need a ridiculously opaque referentially indirecting proxy object. Maybe `std::ref<std::unique_ptr<A>>` (and then use `*a.get() = ...`). Ugh. Must you really be able to pass the argument by value?

Comment: In polite company, you would have a saner API like `std::unique_ptr<A> factory();` and then use it as `auto a = factory();`.

Comment: But if `A` is an incomplete type then I wouldn't be able to have it as a return type

Comment: I never suggested you should have `A` as a return type.

Comment: Oh right, sorry I misunderstood. I'm afraid this is the existing structure I have to work with. :(

Comment: @IvajloDonev `unique_ptr<A>` does not require `A` to be a complete type as long as your use of it doesn't require its definition. In all cases, you *can* declare a function with an incomplete return type.

Comment: Ah, wait: `template <typename T> using some_ptr_type_here = std::unique_ptr<T> &;`.

Comment: "Or is this a case where a raw pointer should be used instead?" A raw pointer wouldn't work either.

Comment: @juanchopanza surely `A**` would work ?

Comment: @IvajloDonev Yes, or a reference to pointer. But the best approach is to return a thing. The caller has much less thinking to do that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I have a setup as below, what would be an appropriate smart pointer type to use?

In this case, no smart pointer at all could do this job. You should just let your factory return a new smart pointer type instead of `void`. Are you perhaps a C programmer?

At any rate, a smart pointer's reference counting usually depends on scoping (and/or explicit increasing). Passing a smart pointer to a function to be populated with a new object kind of breaks that concept. Yes, it's possible to write code that works like that, but usually, smart pointers (especially unique_ptr and cousins) keep internal structures that will make this especially awkward to do.

Really: Just return a new smart pointer, pointing to your new object; don't try pass by value. You'd never pass by value, anyways, if your function was to modify an object, but by reference. Still, returning a new smart pointer is the right thing to do when you have a factory.

Comment: I'm a bit new to c++11 style of coding and so I'm struggling to grasp the limitations and use cases for the different smart pointer types outside of the usual prototypical examples.

Comment: factories returning smart pointers is not a C++11 idiom. GNU Radio has been using that since – 2010, I think. And GNU Radio was a pretty conservative project with that.

Comment: But the reason I have to do it this way is in my full problem I need to pass the entire factory (its a class) to some external code which then executes the factory part asynchronously

Comment: That doesn't mean you have to do this strange thing of passing an object that you want to generate as parameter.

Comment: @IvajloDonev Your factory class could have a `std::unique_ptr<A>` member which gets filled in by the factory method, then your parent thread can call some function which causes the factory class to `std::move` the member pointer out when the object has been generated. That's just one way of doing such a thing.

Comment: @TartanLlama - Thanks this is what I ended up going with in the end to minimize the changes I had to make to the existing code base.